# What would be the correct JSON argument to update roll and connections in street view publish API

Tags: php, json, curl, google-streetview-publish

I am trying to update pose.roll and connections along with other UpdateMasks but only updates heading and pitch, pose.roll remain NULL.

Here is php code

```
<?php
$ch_a = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch_a, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_a, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['access_token'], 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch_a, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch_a, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo/'.$photoId.'?key='.$config['apikey'].'&updateMask=pose.heading,pose.pitch,pose.roll,connections');
curl_setopt($ch_a, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"pose":{"heading": 145.9086485977801, "pitch":3.219209274200196, "roll":"0"}}');
$url = curl_exec($ch_a);
curl_close($ch_a);
echo $url;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an expected behavior.

I've tried this sample request using the Try It! in the documentation.

```
{
  "pose": {
    "roll": 0,
    "latLngPair": {
      "longitude": 118.04944440000001,
      "latitude": 12.5343694
    },
    "heading": 90,
    "pitch": 5.0999984741210938
  }
}
```

Then I received this 200 response:

```
{
  "photoId": {
    "id": "ID"
  },
  "pose": {
    "latLngPair": {
      "latitude": 12.5343694,
      "longitude": 118.04944440000001
    },
    "heading": 90,
    "pitch": 5.0999984741210938
  }
}
```

If you updated `roll` to `0`, then the value will be null. When the value of `roll` is `>0`, it will appear in the response. Example:

```
{
  "photoId": {
    "id": "ID"
  },
  "pose": {
    "latLngPair": {
      "latitude": 12.5343694,
      "longitude": 118.04944440000001
    },
    "heading": 90,
    "pitch": 5.0999984741210938,
    "roll": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: ok its done :D with your JSON @abielita
But seriously i don't know what actually roll do to panorama. The one panorama i publish is draging left and right downwards not perfectly horizontal dragging how can i fix this. https://www.google.com/maps/@30.899548,75.931752,3a,75y,124.88h,75.92t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-DWjr-WDIf-4%2FWVzYffE9IQI%2FAAAAAAAx_qA%2FU7-KYZ1VGrMRH5aLTuG3QaRkFJSwYk8-gCLIBGAYYCw!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-DWjr-WDIf-4%2FWVzYffE9IQI%2FAAAAAAAx_qA%2FU7-KYZ1VGrMRH5aLTuG3QaRkFJSwYk8-gCLIBGAYYCw%2Fno%2Fphoto.jpg!7i11976!8i5988

Comment: You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata#metadata_properties) regarding photo sphere properties.

Comment: Hi @abielita i have an issue with a panorama. Its sloping/skewing while dragging. Is it due to roll value?

Comment: It will depend on how you capture your picture. But you can edit the roll and pitch of each panorama. Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#url_parameters#pitch).

Comment: what value should i use for roll and pitch to preview a perfectly horizontal drag panorama

Comment: Positive values angle the camera up (with 90 degrees indicating straight up); negative values angle the camera down (with -90 indicating straight down).